# AdalServiceException list of error code's defined in Message body

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-active-directory, adal

I'm creating an Azure AD Virtual Machine Monitoring App in ASP.NET and I'm currently working on login error codes using AdalServiceException. I tried searching for a list of the error codes defined in the Exception Message but I couldn't find any documentation about it, not even in the Microsoft Documentation website [Microsoft AdalServiceException Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.adalserviceexception?view=azure-dotnet). I did already test it on 2 error codes that I did find "AADSTS50126" and "AADSTS50034".

*My question:*

Did anyone find the official list of error codes for Azure AD Development Authentication

Comment: Have you looked here? Contains a list of AADSTS error codes and explanations for each error. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes

Comment: This was exactly what I needed at the time, although I don't need it anymore. I don't remember ever finding this page before. But I'm glad it exists if I ever need it. Thanks for taking the time to answer my 2,5 year old question.

Answer (score 1):

I already worked with the library Adal on a big project and according to my experience the redundant errors are of type AdalServiceException with a very precise error message

**MSIS9619**: Is an error related to client account configuration in ad.

**MSIS9604**: is an error related to the configuration of the client account in the database containing the claims.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its not exactly what im looking for. Im looking specifically for an error regarding the authentication when requesting the token using Userpasswordcredentials. Like for example an exception for an expired password or invalid credentials or a user that does not exist inside the Active Directory tenant.